# How to calling private boolean?

Tags: android

This is `boolean` that check service is running or not.
I can't use this in `onCreate`.

CODE:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (ser.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How to check `boolean` in `onCreate`?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I want to use boolean in onCreate.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call in in the same class. If you want to call it outside the class simple make it public instead of private.

Usage example:

```
if(isMyServiceIsRunning){
    //Do something
}
```